# More than one device is performing NAT

Tags: windows, nat

I don't know if this community knows the answer to this problem, but I thought I'd try. I am trying to do some online gaming, but one of the applications (For Honor) created by Ubisoft is not allowing me to game with other players due to my Nat being too strict. I have run the troubleshooting for my network, and the reason my application is not working is because more than one device is performing network address translation (NAT). So the question is, how do I fix this issue? if it is the issue in the first place. It honestly maybe because of Ubisoft.

Comment: Do you have two home routers? If not, then probably your home router is one NAT device and your ISP has another NAT device.

Comment: Describe your network setup in as much detail as you can. What kind of Internet connection do you have? What kind of modem, make and model? What router, make and model? Or are they a single device?

Comment: It doesn't matter how many NATs are ahead of your network, it only affects P2P protocols that try to connect to your client IP directly, instead responding to the same session.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you say your "NAT is too strict"? I guess is a home network with standard NAT, isn't it? I mean, multiple users using same public IP address.

Is the game not allowing more than one player per public IP address? if yes, maybe your solution could be to use VPN networks for each one (except one of you that can still use the normal public IP of your network).

To use VPN connections surf the web, you'll find a lot of VPN services. Most of them are by paying a small quantity per month.

For sure, if you connect through a VPN you'll have more latency in the game. Not sure if your game is a shooter on which every millisecond is matter of life and death or if is an strategy game on which you can play without problems even with almost half second of lag.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going through NAT twice the solution is to remove one of the devices which is doing NAT (or reconfigure it so it doesn't).   If you don't have the ability to do this (either skills or because of technical constraints - like your ISP is doing carrier grade NAT), the work-around is to get a VPN - although this will increase your latency.